# Damaged file handling

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I would like to know if anyone has any advice on handling damaged files with **Apache POI**

I am trying to open a file and am receiving this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream$LeftoverDataException: Initialisation of record 0x1C left 2 bytes remaining still to be read.
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream.hasNextRecord(RecordInputStream.java:156)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactoryInputStream.nextRecord(RecordFactoryInputStream.java:231)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecords(RecordFactory.java:480)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:301)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:95)
    at ExcelImporter.EditFileImportDialog.main(EditFileImportDialog.java:409)
```

Here is an SSCCE

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class EditFileImportDialog {

    /* Omitted irrelevent code */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("Z:\\Path\\To\\File_causing_the_trouble.xls");
        try {
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);  // Line 409 for ref to the exception stack trace
            System.out.println(wb);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This happens with this file only, and the exception is not thrown if I open the file in excel and save it, then try to open it with `POI`.  Any suggestion as to how I could handle this?

**EDIT:**

As a note, my issue may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457390/jxl-and-apache-poi-parsing-excel-with-attached-image-objects), but upgrading `POI` did not fix my issue and there are dissimilarities with the described file.  I have searched around for similar answers but perhaps if someone knows what's wrong with the excel file itself, I can write something to patch the file.

**EDIT 2**

The file creation is not in my control.  Excel fixes the file itself just upon opening and re-saving it.  My question though is whether anyone can think of a way to adjust/augment POI to handle this damaged file in the same way that excel is able to fix the issue.

**EDIT 3**

In response to several comments/answers:

My end goal would be to not use excel at all.

1. File is sent in.
2. Program runs.
3. Handles the error.
4. Processes data.

Comment: If this is part of an interactive process (like a user uploading a file) then your best bet is probably to advise the user that there is a problem and suggest that they open and re-save the document before trying again.

Comment: @ninesided it's not part of an upload process, however the user will be able to open and resave the file each time, but this is a file that comes in every day and there is some bug on the delivery end which is out of our control.  If there is no way to programmatically handle such errors we can resort to the open/resave method and let excel handle the error fixing, but this is not preferred, as this is an effort towards a single click process.

Comment: can you provide any detail on the source of the XLS file? I've seen cases where systems export both .CSV and .HTML files with a .XLS extension. In both these cases Excel could open the data, but it's possible that POI doesn't check the file headers and makes assumptions about the format based on the extension.

Comment: @ninesided good suggestion, but i've checked on this, I already have code to handle for _misnamed_ html/csv files, but this one still fails though that was not included in my example.  It is a "valid" `.xls` file apart from the indicated damage. As for more info on the file: It is an auto-generated statement from a bank which has been notified about the bug and their team is working it.  I would like to work towards my program being able to handle these sorts of issues on its own though in case they pop up in the future for other files.

Comment: Your best bet would be to open a new bug in the POI bugzilla, and attach it there

Comment: You could try to use POI event API or even low-level API to read xls in a less strict manner than usermodel api does. http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api

Comment: I would compare (hexadecimal code) the file before and after opening and saving with excel. This way you can see what to do to patch received files.

Comment: Perhaps you could run the spreadsheet through the open office api, microsoft api or some web service and re-save the spreadsheet with that service or API.  Perhaps save the spreadsheet in an older version format that POI can't tolerate.  The idea is to ask something other than POI to scrub the file a bit before passing it to POI.  Also be sure you are using latest POI, 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.10-FINAL'

Comment: @littleLouito  I actually lucked out and got the source generating these files to provide a `.csv` version instead which I had already written a convertor into `POI` for.

Comment: @javajon That is a good idea!  I will try this out and see if I can improve my sanitizing algorithm.  I am using the most recent version of POI.

Comment: Do you have access to programmatically open excel and reserve it on YOUR end?  A quick applescript could do the trick.

Comment: @ergonaut I do have access to create something like that but I am looking to create a POI solution.  Dependency on excel like that is undesirable.

Comment: If you save the file as an xlsx, do you still have the problem?  If so, you can expand the file and check which area is the culprit.

Comment: @ergonaut save the file from where? excel?  The file is generated elsewhere and then sent over to me.

Comment: get the xls, open it up in excel and save as xlsx.  Then check.

Comment: @ergonaut Again, I am looking for a solution that will fix the xls file without excel.  I mentioned in my Question that saving the file via excel, to xls or xlsx, corrects the error.  I think POI should be able to replicate the behavior of Excel.

Comment: @FarmerJoe, I'm only suggesting to see if it DOES produce an error saving as xlsx (and importing).  You didn't specifically say this format.  Then it might give more clues as to a root cause.

Comment: @ergonaut the error is corrected by excel upon saving the file in either xls or xlsx format.  The root cause is that the record indicated by the Exception thrown by POI has the incorrect number of bytes.

Comment: can you provide us the file to check.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using HSSFWorkbook to open .xls files.

You could use the following code to check how POI respond determining xls format.

```
private boolean isExcel(InputStream i) throws IOException {
return (POIFSFileSystem.hasPOIFSHeader(i) || POIXMLDocument.hasOOXMLHeader(i));
}
```

I would use :

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
```

Instead of :

```
File file = new File("Z:\\Path\\To\\File_causing_the_trouble.xls");
```

Did you check what is wrong with the cell 0x1C  in your file ?

Comment: As per the [Apache POI Documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), you're much better off using a File rather than an InputStream if it's an option

Comment: I did check, there is a simply a problem with the generation of the file (which is out of my control).

If you look through the docs the method [create](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create(java.io.File)) appropriately chooses the correct format.  My question is aimed more towards seeing if the same error correction Excel exhibits could be replicated in some fashion for POI.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: You could overload the classes you need to properly handle the error.

Comment: @XavierBouclet do you have any suggestion on how to properly handle the error?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the create method in WorkbookFactory ? After that you could override WorkbookFactory and use your own create method. Because your problem is related to one case you should be able to do so. Can be tricky though.

Answer (score 1):

Exception in thread main is not a coding problem. You should replace wrong cell references in Excel-Workbook!

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream$LeftoverDataException: 
Initialisation of record 0x23 left 12 bytes remaining still to be read.

This Exception is thrown when i try to open an Excel-Workbook with POI HSSF, that contains a DDE Cell Reference. I have this problem with a cell reference type of 'Excel.Type.12' e.g.:
=Excel.Sheet.12|'\servername\pathname\Workbook.xlsx'!'!Sheetname!Z23S22'

Workaround: Replace the reference with a reference of type 'Sheet' e.g.:
='Drive:\pathname[Workbook.xlsx]Sheetname'!$V$23

Save your Workbook and try it again.

Comment: The file creation is not in my control, the bug exists on the side of the people creating the file.  I know I can edit the file myself and fix the cell using excel.  Excel in fact fixes the file itself just upon opening and re-saving it fixes the problem.  My question though is whether anyone can think of a way to adjust POI to handle this damaged file in the same way that excel handles the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to create a new file and make it a point to remember that you close the file before executing the program. That would be the simplest solution.

Comment: You should provide a simple code example to support your answer.

Comment: Agreed @pczeus. But why write a code when you can create a new file to be written.

Comment: @SanketGupte I do not understand your suggestion.  My problem is that a file that I need to read is sent with an error at the indicated record.  I want to be able to have POI fix the error and read the file.  I never open the file or create a new file...I need to read information from a given file.  Excel is able to fix the error, so I believe there should be a solution we could come up with to mimic Excel's behavior.

Comment: Wait. Now I don't get it. Do you want to read a file or write it??

Comment: @SanketGupte I am reading data from an excel file that is sent to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an XSSFWorkbook instead from a FileInputStream.

With changes your sample would look like:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class EditFileImportDialog {

    /* Omitted irrelevent code */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file = "Z:\\Path\\To\\File_causing_the_trouble.xls";
        try {
            InputStream databaseFile = new FileInputStream(file);
            XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(databaseFile);  
            System.out.println(wb);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `XSSFWorkbook` is used to open `.xlsx` type files, your proposed solution throws an `InvalidFormatException` and does not remedy the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already checked, but if not, see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47251 if helps. It has similar problem(s) and you may find answer on how to handle it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Rather than just linking to a bug report (even if it's marked as resolved), it would be more helpful if you could try and find the actual solution. Otherwise, a comment would be more appropriate (you'll be able to comment on other's posts once you get a bit more reputation on SO).